# wget hangs when downloading ruby file on debian 10

Tags: networking, virtualbox, wget, bridge

I've got debian10 installed in a new VirtualBox 6.10 image and I'm trying to wget ruby and I'm getting this error;

```
wget -d http://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.7/ruby-2.7.1.tar.bz2
DEBUG output created by Wget 1.20.1 on linux-gnu.

Reading HSTS entries from /home/deploy/.wget-hsts
URI encoding = ‘UTF-8’
Converted file name 'ruby-2.7.1.tar.bz2' (UTF-8) -> 'ruby-2.7.1.tar.bz2' (UTF-8)
--2020-06-20 21:47:58--  http://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.7/ruby-2.7.1.tar.bz2
Resolving cache.ruby-lang.org (cache.ruby-lang.org)... 151.101.81.178, 2a04:4e42:13::434
Caching cache.ruby-lang.org => 151.101.81.178 2a04:4e42:13::434
Connecting to cache.ruby-lang.org (cache.ruby-lang.org)|151.101.81.178|:80... connected.
Created socket 3.
Releasing 0x0000559037039410 (new refcount 1).

---request begin---
GET /pub/ruby/2.7/ruby-2.7.1.tar.bz2 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Wget/1.20.1 (linux-gnu)
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: identity
Host: cache.ruby-lang.org
Connection: Keep-Alive

---request end---
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
---response begin---
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-amz-id-2: jNncZWwFSDNpAZf7MTPbl/5NjaQmHfLVkliz9EUFtmiU0znHJZ1qjhP120rm83pSsoyEMYsD2Bw=
x-amz-request-id: 452C95AE7903C760
Last-Modified: Tue, 31 Mar 2020 13:12:51 GMT
ETag: "2e18bd214b76d0bcf9781c9d212f27c6-2"
x-amz-version-id: zx1AE1dmawAEA16qs3I7uHPSp0Go.dHL
Content-Type: application/x-tar
Server: AmazonS3
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Age: 290579
Content-Length: 14684616
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Sat, 20 Jun 2020 11:47:58 GMT
Via: 1.1 varnish
Connection: keep-alive
X-Served-By: cache-mel19025-MEL
X-Cache: HIT
X-Cache-Hits: 0
X-Timer: S1592653679.667345,VS0,VE3

---response end---
200 OK
Registered socket 3 for persistent reuse.
Length: 14684616 (14M) [application/x-tar]
Saving to: ‘ruby-2.7.1.tar.bz2.2’

ruby-2.7.1.tar.bz2.2        0%[                                      ]       0  --.-KB/s
```

It just sits there. If I try downloading with the exact same command on my host it works every time.

**Update**

Changing the VM's network from Bridge to NAT I can run the wget command fine in the VM.

It must have something to do with the bridge.

The bridged settings I've been using are;

```
Attached to: Bridged Adapter
Name: enx8cae4ce92c47 (usb to NIC adapter)
Adapter Type: PCnet-FAST III (Am79C973) 
Promiscuous Mode: Deny
Cable Connected: true
```

Comment: Try to download with a browser or `curl`, from the same host. If it works, then it is a wget problem. If it doesn't work, you might have a network issue (policies for example).

Comment: Can you access that site or the internet at all on your Debian 10 VM? I was able to use that same command to successfully download that file on my Debian 10 VM.

Comment: Eduarado: Tried curl and it also doesn't work